# Carrierwave + Carrierwave_Backgrounder + Sidekiq without database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, process, triggers, backgroundworker, carrierwave

I am trying to setup  Carrierwave + Carrierwave_Backgrounder + Sidekiq in my project. I am using tableless models since I am doing everything using WebServices from another server.

This is the code of one of my models:

```
def save
    self.store_avatar!
end
```

If I don't save the object itself to the database the job is never enqueued. Any idea how can I force the process to be triggered?